# Excel - SUMIF a range using vertical and horizontal criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I’m trying to create a formula that sums a range based on multiple criteria in Excel.

One criteria range is in a tab called 'Budget Forecast Actuals' in B13:B54 (shown in yellow) – with the criteria being in a tab called 'Financials Template' in cell I4.

The second criteria range is in the tab called 'Budget Forecast Actuals' in cells V6:AG6 (shown in red) – with the criteria being in the 'Financials Template' tab in cell D5.

And the range that require summing is in the 'Budget Forecast Actuals' tab in cells V13:AG32 (shown in green).

Can someone please help me with the formula required? I've tried all the usual tricks (even resorting to asking ChatGPT who suggested the same formulae I've been trying).

So far I have tried (amongst others)...

```
=SUMIFS('Budget Forecast Actuals'!V13:AG32, 'Budget Forecast Actuals'!B13:B54,
 'Financials Template'!I4, 'Budget Forecast Actuals'!V6:AG6, 'Financials Template'!D5)
```

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Budget Forecast Actuals'!B13:B54='Financials Template'!I4)*
('Budget Forecast Actuals'!V6:AG6='Financials Template'!D5)*('Budget Forecast Actuals'!V13:AG32))
```

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note the formula works when I have the sum range as a single row (i.e. V13:AG13) - but as soon as I extend it over more than one row the formula stops working - any help is greatly appreciated  

Comment: Hi @Matteous can you post a sample copiable data using **[MarkdownTableGenerator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** that would help to copy the data and provide solution accordingly. Please show the expected output. Thanks

Comment: Thank you both for your help - much appreciated. I tried =SUM((A2:A7="a")*(B1:G1="o")*(B2:G7)) and it results in a #SPILL! error - and I tried the update suggestion above to no avail. It would be easier to paste the spreadsheet in its entirety rather than into the Markdown Table Generator - is there a preferred way of attaching the full spreadsheet? Note there's no macros or anything of that nature

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your kind response again, you can do that. using a one-drive link or drop box link, by editing the post or while typing a comment you see the help option click on it, it will guide you so if you have a link write in this manner -- [ Open square brackets --> name it --> close square brackets ] --> ( Open round brackets --> paste the link --> close round brackets )

Comment: [OneDrive Link] - (https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZnwIqQonM1arObnsdsTdQ21Dc?e=ry1bwH)

Thank you all for your help - I've highlighted my troublesome cells in red on the Financials Template tab

Comment: Formula is updated: `=SUM(($D5='Budget Forecast Actuals'!$V$6:$AG$6)*(I$4='Budget Forecast Actuals'!$B$13:$B$54)*('Budget Forecast Actuals'!$V$13:$AG$54))`

Comment: If you are not using `MS365` then use `SUMPRODUCT()` instead of `SUM()` --> `=SUMPRODUCT(($D5='Budget Forecast Actuals'!$V$6:$AG$6)*(I$4='Budget Forecast Actuals'!$B$13:$B$54)*('Budget Forecast Actuals'!$V$13:$AG$54))`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=SUM((A2:A7="a")*(B1:G1="o")*(B2:G7))
```

Result and explanation:

[image]

Update:

Your second formula should work if you update either `'Budget Forecast Actuals'!B13:B54` to `'Budget Forecast Actuals'!B13:B32` or `'Budget Forecast Actuals'!V13:AG32` to `'Budget Forecast Actuals'!V13:AG54` - those ranges must have same length.

Comment: Thank you both for your help - much appreciated.

I tried =SUM((A2:A7="a")*(B1:G1="o")*(B2:G7)) and it results in a #SPILL! error - and I tried the update suggestion above to no avail. 

It would be easier to paste the spreadsheet in its entirety rather than into the Markdown Table Generator - is there a preferred way of attaching the full spreadsheet? Note there's no macros or anything of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all - your answers were correct - and after much wailing and gnashing of teeth I found out that it was the values in my V13:AG32 section that were causing the problem. V13:AG32 contains essential formulae (which I couldn't include on the OneDrive share) and if they found a blank cell or returned a zero I set the formula to return a blank ("") - once I changed this to return a zero (0) instead it worked fine.

You're amazing - I really appreciate your help